# How to add image for custom taxonomy

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, theme-development, customization

I was trying to add category images for custom taxonomy I am using this plugin [taxonomy-images](https://wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomy-images/)  but I don't know how to get that custom taxonomy image

I tried to keep print `apply_filters( 'taxonomy-images-queried-term-image', '' );`

but not getting image in taxonomy page

here's my `taxonomy.php` code

```
<?php $term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) ); ?>
<h2>  <?php echo $term->name;?></h2>

<?php query_posts(array( 'post_type'=>'deals', 'brands' => $term->slug, 'posts_per_page' => -1 )); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

  <!--your content goes here-->



            <p>Deal Name: <?php echo the_field('deal_title'); ?></p>
            <p>test:<?php echo  the_field('dealdescription'); ?></p> 
<?php
print apply_filters( 'taxonomy-images-queried-term-image', '' );

 ?>         


  <!--your content goes here-->

 <?php endwhile; else: ?>
    <h3>Sorry, no matched your criteria.</h3>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [get_object_taxonomies()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_object_taxonomies) as your solution.

Returns all the taxonomies for a post type or post object:

```
<?php get_object_taxonomies( $object, $output ); ?>
```

Have you tried anything? something like this?

```
// taxonomy term archives
$post_type = get_post_type(); // find out if CPT
$taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies($post_type); // Find taxonomies
if($taxonomies){
    foreach($taxonomies as $taxonomy){
        // only want hierarchial -- no tags please
        if(is_taxonomy_hierarchical($taxonomy)){

            $terms = get_terms($taxonomy); // find out "terms" e.g. catoegries, for each taxonomy

            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {  ?>
                $term_link = get_term_link($term->slug, $taxonomy);
                $term_name = $term->name;

                //Image section like below...
                if (function_exists('z_taxonomy_image_url')) { ?>

                    <img class="category-thumbnail" src="<?php if (function_exists('z_taxonomy_image_url')) echo z_taxonomy_image_url(); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"/>
                <?php } 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This how you can get taxonomy with image.

The Categories Images Plugin(https://wordpress.org/plugins/categories-images/) allow you to add image with category or taxonomy.

Comment: is it use full custom post type

Comment: i was not able to see any image upload in my custom taxonomy i added this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/categories-images/screenshots/

Answer (score 0):

Please try replacing

```
print apply_filters( 'taxonomy-images-queried-term-image', '' );
```

with

```
print apply_filters( 'taxonomy-images-list-the-terms', '' );
```

For WordPress default post type, I created category.php template and altered your code as below. It is showing category image. You can view the snippet [here](https://gist.github.com/ItsMePN/5feb667279e6ee5d60cb#file-category-php)

Comment: i created also but i am not getting image

Comment: i dont want to filter category but my post type is deals in that i have categories i want to get with post type

Comment: Please provide the code which you used to register custom post type and taxonomy so that I may assist

Comment: i register post type to deals and taxonomy to customcategorie

Comment: i used cpt ui  plugins for creating post types and taxonomy

Comment: can we chat instead of it